# Text detection feature extraction from text document images

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision, ocr

I want to develop an application to detect text from scanned documents which may contain mixed text, graph, images, etc .. I think I can use sliding window technique of fixed size and using a feedforward NN or SVM to classify these regions, but I'm stuck with feature extraction phase what are common used features extraction methods to use ?

Comment: You've decided on the best technique to learn with, but not on what inputs (features) it will operate on?  That sounds a bit backwards.

Comment: If the documents have typed text rather than handwritten text, you could probably even get away with template matching rather than a more complex machine learning algorithm. If the characters are handwritten, you may also be able to use the raw pixels as features and an algorithm like k-nearest neighbours, depending on how clear the handwriting is.

Comment: @eigenchris all text images are machine printed

Comment: @IbrahimAmer a simple method would be to just compare every letter with a set of examples using a metric like [mean square error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error) or [cross correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation#Normalized_cross-correlation).

Answer (score 1):

If all the characters are machine printed, one of easy and accurate feature would be the normalized density value of each pre-processed character image.

There you can divide the image in to fixed number of segments and calculate the normalized density value for each segment. Then you will get vector of density values for each character and proceed with the classification with NN or SVM.

Comment: thank you sir for your answer, can you elaborate how to calculate normalized density value for each window ?

Comment: normalized density value can be define as,  total density (sum of all density of all pixels of the segment) / # segments . you can easily develop some algorithm for this.

Answer (score 1):

The following might help you. Perhaps it is overkill for what you are trying to do, but it is meant to identify text regions in an image.

"Robust Text Detection in Natural Images with Edge-enhanced Maximally Stable Extremal Regions" (http://web.stanford.edu/~hchen2/papers/ICIP2011_RobustTextDetection.pdf)

You can find a related project on github (I have not used this myself): https://github.com/subokita/Robust-Text-Detection but it might be worth a try with your example images.

There are a lot of scientific papers about page/text segmentation, search for those terms on google scholar and you can find older, less complex approaches. One example is "Page segmentation and classification using fast feature extraction and connectivity analysis" (http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.55.527&rep=rep1&type=pdf)